# Checking class's thread-safety in intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, thread-safety

I heard that there is a possibility to check if the class is thread-safe.
Is it so? How to do that?

Comment: Checking for thread safety can be done by going through the code of the class as well I guess !

Comment: You can enable some checks that are off by default. But all this is just simple checks, like `wait`ing outside of a loop. Nothing can prove your code is thread-safe, not even tests.

Comment: but they can help to avoid simple errors, can't it? This will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was HOW so here is the answer:
go to `Settings->Inspections` and there choose `Threading issues` and `Concurrency annotation issues`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to look at [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) project. It makes static analysis of code and possibly can find some concurrency problems. There is also plugin for intelliJ which can be integrated with this tool.

Comment: IntelliJ itself comes with a quite good range of bug-spotting heuristics.